# Restrict activities or android component based on user profile

Tags: android, android-activity, permissions, tree

I am writing an application where, after successfull login and based on the user profile, the user can only see certain activities. For instance, if user has `profilA`, he can only see Activities `A, B, C`. If he has `profilB`, he can only sees Activities `D,F,G`.

Note that I could write 2 applications and my problem is solved easily but the requirements are the app should manage `profileA` and `profileB`.

I was thinking about custom permissions to implement this. Where each activity will be restricted with a custom permissions. For instance, Activities `A,B and C` would be restricted with `com.myapp.permissions.profilA`. And Activities `D,F and G` would be restricted with `com.myapp.permissions.profilB`.

While searching again, I have found the [permission-tree](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-tree-element.html) element and the [PackageManager.addPermission(PermissionInfo info)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#addPermission(android.content.pm.PermissionInfo)).

The javadoc of `addPermission`says :

> Add a new dynamic permission to the system. For this to work, your package must have defined a permission tree through the  tag in its manifest. A package can only add permissions to trees that were defined by either its own package or another with the same user id; a permission is in a tree if it matches the name of the permission tree + ".": for example, "com.foo.bar" is a member of the permission tree "com.foo".

The idea that I have is, define a permission-tree, after successfull login, based on the user profile, "sets the custom permissions" of the application. I don't know if it's possible.

It's a similar feature when certain apps hide some admins features to their users. I am thinking of similar functionality.

Is it possible to achieve this functionality? Or do I need to think for another solution?

I am open to all propositions.

Comment: how about, before calling an intent to open an activity, implement a check to see which profile the user belongs to and the call intents accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to go about about.  In your API, create a user_code for each user so that after a successful login, you can get the user_code for the currently logged in user.  Once you get the code say in the Home/Dashboard Activity, you can check if the user is allowed to access a certain activity and if they are not allowed, you can probably return an alert dialog telling them that they don't have the rights.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that defining custom permissions to restrict access to certain activities is not exactly what you need. Seems to me that you're going on the wrong direction...as the documentation states...[creating custom permissions is relatively uncommon](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html#CreatingPermissions)...I mean permissions were designed to reduce security issues and sandbox applications from each other....the latter doesn't seem to be your case.

Anyway, it is extremely uncommon...IMHO, to create custom permissions for the mere purpose to restrict access to certain activities. Especially, because the same way you login a user and the same way you determine what a specific user is allowed to do...it's exactly the same way you can determine when to restrict access to a specific part of your app

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why you would need to rely on the permission system to do this.  What I'm thinking is that  you can just create logic to disable whatever features that would lead to those Activities from being launched based on the logged in profile.

If your activities don't have any filters that would allow them to be launched implicitly by another intent, then that means your app complete control over when they're launched.

Answer (score 0):

Use the login result to control what you display to the user.  If you wanted to, you could create two separate XML layout files.  One that has buttons for A, B, and C, and the other that has buttons for D, E, and F.

Just because an Activity exists doesn't mean it's automatically displayed to the user as an "entry point". You're doing that through what you display in other activities.